# Variable inspector in jupyter notebook not working for R

Tags: r, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, conda

I'd like to be able to have a variable inspector in jupyter notebook in VS code for R that works similarly to that for Python, it seems to me that such thing exists but I'm not able to find a way to display it. I am using a conda environment where I have installed both a Python kernel and a R kernel, R is properly working when I select the proper kernel in the environment.

The R extension that can be installed in vs code doesn't seem to recognize variables in a .ipynb file (it can display them properly in a .R file though, I suppose that it uses the R package that is installed globally in my machine) and the jupyter terminal that works with Python doesn't display any variable while working with a R kernel.

Is there something that I'm missing? I've tried searching online but there is nothing that seems to work to solve my problem.

Comment: What is the extension? Please edit the question to include this information.

Comment: I've installed the R extension for vs code from REditorSupport

Comment: You may want to ask them directly, i.e., [file an Issue on their repository](https://github.com/REditorSupport/vscode-R/issues).